# When would GC free variable set on express app?

Tags: node.js, express, garbage-collection

I'm trying to store some persistent data on an express app. 
In my following example, I have a function `getProductPrice` that stores a mapping from product names to its prices. If the price does not exist it fetches the data externally and stores it in an object (`productNameToPrice`). `getProductPrice` is set on the express app with `app.set('getProductPrice', getProductPrice)`

Would the mapping `productNameToPrice` persist as long as app is running or would the GC at some point free up the memory?

Here is the example code:

```
//Some external api that gives product prices
const getProductPriceFromApi = require('getProductPriceFromApi');

const productNameToPrice = {};
const getProductPrice = (productName) => {
  if (productName in productNameToPrice) {
    return productNameToPrice[productName];
  }
  const productPrice = getProductPriceFromApi(productName);
  productNameToPrice[productName] = productPrice;
  return productPrice;
};
```

```
...

const getProductPrice = require('./getProductPrice');
app.set('getProductPrice', getProductPrice);

...
```

Comment: Is `productNameToPrice` a local variable? Because if so, it will be garbage collected after the scope is freed up. If it's global, then the value would be retained until reassigned. Since it's a `const` that won't happen, but you can still change the shape of the object which will free up old values.

Comment: What is the scope of your first code block?  Is that module scope?  Something set on the `app` object with `app.set()` will not be eligible for garbage collection until the `app` object itself is eligible for garbage collection (probably never unless  you shut-down the Express server and overwrite any saved instances of `app`).

Comment: `productNameToPrice` is in global scope, but only set indirectly on the app over  the function using it (`getProductPrice `).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When would GC free variable set on express app?

An object set with `app.set()` will never be garbage collected as long as the `app` it was set on is still alive and there are still reachable references to it in some variables. So, in a normal Express app design, it would never be garbage collected until the process was shut-down.  To get the `app` to be garbage collected, you should have to stop the server and overwrite all possible references to the `app` variable so there were no longer any reachable references to that `app` object.

So, as long as you're not purposely doing that, the data you set with `app.set()` will not be garbage collected.  A garbage collector's job is to clean up things when they are no longer reachable by any live code and can no longer be used in any way.  They will not clean up something that can still be reached by your code.  So, since `app.get()` can retrieve a value set with `app.set()`, that value can't be garbage collected until there is no code that has any reference to `app` any more.